# scikit image contour completion

Tags: python, scikit-image

I am working with the following image.

[image: Concentric Contours]

My aim is to get the curvature of the outermost circle in the central part of the image.

**AFTER CANNY EDGE FILITER**

[image: CANNY EDGE FILTER]

My focus is the concentric circles in the center of the image.
I need to be able to get the radius of curvature of the outermost circle.
I have tried find_contours, but it produces thousands of colored disconnected contours.

Regards,
Richard Madson